# vuetify-form-base Form not Load in Production Mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, dynamic-forms

I Use [vuetify-form-base](https://github.com/wotamann/vuetify-form-base) in Nuxt-Vue project and evrythings is OK in development mode(npm run dev)
When I switch to production mode(npm run start); forms not load and no errors or warnings occurred.

my `nuxt.config.js` file is:

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  ssr: false,
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - nuxt-form-sample',
    title: 'nuxt-form-sample',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and vuetify-form-base usage is:

```html
<div>
  <v-form-base :schema="schema" :model="model"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you shared but this is not a Nuxt project. Also, what is your `target`? Default one? Tried `npm run build` before `npm run start`?

Comment: I tried this but not work. the simplest way to test this is to create nuxt project and add vuetify-form-base with a simple form to it. remind to set ssr:false in nuxt.config.js

Comment: `vuetify-form-base` is not trivial and we will probably need your actual code to see what is the issue. We don't even have the `schema` here. Also, refering to my previous comment, what did no work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue
https://github.com/wotamann/vuetify-form-base/issues/50
In the SSR mode form didn't render correctly!

Solution1:

You should use the 'v-mask' package and import the main component file in the vuetify-form-base package.

You should export this package in a plugin like as below:
Vue.component('VueMask', () => import('v-mask'))

after that add the main file component to your project:

https://github.com/wotamann/vuetify-form-base/blob/master/dist/src/vFormBase.vue

Alternative solution:

- You can use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-form-base-ssr package.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not clear for me so I want to tell you easy way to fix this problem step by step.
I fixed the problem after it take me plenty of time here is the solution :
1- install v-mask package
2- just copy `https://github.com/wotamann/vuetify-form-base/blob/master/dist/src/vFormBase.vue` to your components folder
3- use `Vue.component('VueMask', () => import('v-mask'))` in your plugins
4- then just remove form-base import in pages.